# $\lim \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h}$ as h goes to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h} =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{(h+x)^2}-e^{x^2}}{h}\bigg|_{x=0} = \left(e^{x^2}\right)'\bigg|_{x=0} = 2 \cdot 0 \cdot e^0 =  0. $

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Also you can do L'Hopitals

Comment: Also you can do Taylor series $e^{h^2}=1+h^2+O(h^4)$

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.


$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}{2he^{h^2}} = 0$, right? @avid19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h^2}\frac{h^2}{h}
\to 0
$
since
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h^2}
= 1
$
and
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2}{h}
= 0
$.

Comment: I think this is the way I was supposed to do it, thanks!